# Array in React updates before changes should be applied

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am trying to understand why my array updates its values before I want to apply changes to it with the function `createRandomGrid`. When I print the array before and after the modification, it prints the same result.

Can someone please explain me how this occurs?

```js
let sudokuGrid = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];

console.log(sudokuGrid)
createRandomGrid(sudokuGrid);
console.log(sudokuGrid)

function createRandomGrid(board) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
      if (board[i][j] === 0) {
        for (let k = 1; k <= 9; k++) {
          let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
          if (isValidNode(i, j, num, board)) {
            board[i][j] = num;
            if (createRandomGrid(board)) return true;
            board[i][j] = 0;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: You need to add to your question the code of the function createRandomGrid

Comment: Probably due to the lazy evaluation of console logged objects in the browser - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chrome-s-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-objects

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answers. I added the function to the snippet.

Comment: Probably because it doesn't

Comment: Please keep clicking "Run code snippet" until it demonstrates the error you believe it to be. Currently it is just throwing at error about the missing definition of the `isValidNode` function. Please do this yourself; you shouldn't need readers to tell you when your posted code demonstrates the error you are talking about.

Comment: The function shall find a random solution for the empty grid. But it logs the random grid twice to the console.

Comment: technically, it logs the grid without the values to the console. Then, when you expand it, you get the value of the grid at the point in time in which you expanded it, which is *after* it was changed. See brian thompson's link.

Comment: By the way, one of the principle tenets of React is immutability of data. You are mutating the data in `createRandomGrid`, thus violating that tenet. Instead, create a new copy of the array, with the changed data. One easy way to do that is via the `map` function.

Comment: Great, thanks for all your answers and advises.